# Why does my Applescript run in the Terminal using osascript on Snow Leopard but not on Lion?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, applescript, osascript

I have the following Applescript which runs fine from the applescript editor in both Snow Leopard and Lion. I can also run it using osascript via terminal on Snow Leopard but not on Lion. The code is as follows

```
tell application "System Events"
try
    get process "Mathematica"
on error -- Not running, launch and run
    launch application "Mathematica"
    -- May need to wait until application finishes launching
    repeat while "Mathematica" is not in name of processes
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
end try
end tell
tell application "Mathematica"
activate
do script "notebook0=NotebookEvaluate[\"/Users/me/file.nb\"];
           Clear[notebook0];NotebookClose[EvaluationNotebook[]]"
end tell
```

The script opens and executes a Mathematica script. It is successful for the scenarios above but when I try to run it using osascript in Lion I get a Mathematica window which states that "the requested file could not be found or accessed".

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch application "Mathematica", I suggest you provide the full path for your application.